# Looking for a jQuery effect to gradually reveal a hidden DIV/image

Tags: jquery, image, navigation, show, slide

It may be that I am missing something obvious, but I can't work out how to reveal a hidden image/DIV slowly, so that it is shown from top to bottom.

If you look at this jsfiddle you will see the image that I am trying to reveal using 'show' in jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/nickharambee/Lj7z9/13/

The trouble with 'show' is that it grows the image from top left.

What I am looking for is an effect that hopefully is clear from these images:

[image][image][image][image][image]

i.e. the red 'home' image/DIV is gradually revealed from top to bottom so that it overlays the brown 'home' image.

Is it possible to achieve an effect like this with jQuery and if so what would be the best method? I am wanting to use this transition on all of the images in my nav bar.

Thanks,

Nick

**ADDED CODE**

*HTML:*

```
<li id="test2"><img src="images/home3.png"></li>
```

*CSS:*

```
li {
    background: url('images/sprite.png') no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

*SCRIPT:*

```
$("li#test2").hover(
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          'background-position-y': '-40'
        }, 500);
      },
      function () {
        $(this).animate({
          'background-position-y': '0'
        }, 500);
      }
    );
```

Comment: one way to do it is to create a punched PNG and animate div's behind the punched out png.  I believe there might also be a method of using HTML5 canvas to do this.

Comment: @Xavier. Thanks, I created a punched PNG and I animated a sprite with two colours as a background image.  I have added the code I used at the end of my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the hover image in a div that has this style class:

```
.blind {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That makes the image invisible because its container (the div) is zero-height and its overflow (the whole image) is hidden.

Then animate div.blind like so:

```
$('.blind').animate({height: "40px"});
```

Now the image's container is big enough for the whole hover image.  The hover image is gradually revealed, from top to bottom.

I have this working at: http://jsfiddle.net/cHt8V/1/

Comment: Thanks.  That works fine, and I have now implemented it on this page (the third nav item).

Answer (score 1):

To avoid these jquery animation method flickers I'd animate the height of a container of the "hover" look, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7z9/16/

Comment: thanks, this is the effect I am looking for.  Would I need a mouseout function for reversing the effect when the nav image is not being hovered over?

Comment: indeed you would. if you follow my example you reverse the height of the a tag back to 0, thus reducing the visible area of the hover image bit by bit. the only difference would be that you hide the img.hover only after the animation has finished - that is the function() as 3rd parameter with the instruction to hide the img: http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7z9/21/

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by using `slideDown('slow')` in jQuery for animation.
You can control speed by using `slow` or `fast` or `normal` as parameter.

updated the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lj7z9/14/

Comment: Thanks, but slideDown isn't giving me the effect I want, i.e. it is not a straight slide down in such a way that reveals another image over the background image.  I know it may not be clear what I am looking for, but I was hoping that the above images would make it clear!

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 ways I can think of to do this, and one is creating an animated image (which you don't want).
The other way is inspired by youlove.us's old homepage (they used a white png with transparency, with the words "cut out" from the background. This was layered over a coloured background that constantly scrolled.)

You could adapt this by using 3 divs with absolute positioning and suitable z-index values to place them on top of one another:
the bottom has a grey background
the top is an image with the word "home" cut out so the grey shows through
the middle is the one that you will animate... create a div with red background and animate it using toggle() (or slideup & slidedown if you prefer)

I hope this makes sense?