# Disable img scaling/resizing? (How to get "reveal effect"?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an img element. But I want to turn off its resizing "ability" while I make it grow in width.

This is an animation that gives the appearance of me slowly revealing the image from left to right.

But if the resizing/scaling to the width is on **it doesn't look like the image is slowly revealing but it looks like its slowly growing in width, which is not what I want.**

I'm using javascript to make it grow in width, is there a way to make the image resizing turn off? Maybe I can set the css **display** or **position** to something?

I am developing only for the iPad, so I the best solution is a CSS3 attribute or HTML5 method.

Comment: The css-background property is not (normally?) affected by the img elements width, although there are other approaches (such as hiding the img -- fixed width -- inside a growing div as well).

Comment: U could use jquery show as explained in http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a lot like [another question from today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8465048/looking-for-a-jquery-effect-to-gradually-reveal-a-hidden-div-image).

You can put your image in a div; give the div the styles

```
overflow:hidden; 
width:0px;
```

then animate the div's width to the full width of your image, and it will be slowly revealed from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy using a wrapping `div` and `overflow:hidden;` I used CSS3 animation, but the concept is what's important.

```
div{overflow:hidden; 
    -webkit-animation: imageHide 5s infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes imageHide {
        0%   { width: 0px; }
        100% { width: 300px; }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ERM6J/)